# Writing a get next token function

Tags: c, parsing, static

Given a C-string: how would I be able to write a function that will get the next token in the string, and a function that will peek the next token and return that without using global variables?

What I'm trying to do is have a static variable that will hold the string, and when called, it would just increment a pointer, and it will reset that static variable throwing out the token that has been retrieved. The problem is: how would I be able to differentiate between the first call (when it will actually store the string) and the other calls, when I am just retrieving it?

Any thoughts on this?

**EDIT:**
Here's what I have now that "works" but I want to make sure that it should actually work and its not just a coincidence of a pointer being null:

```
char next_token(char *line) {
    static char *p;
    if (p == NULL)
        p = line;
    else {
        char next_token = p[0];
        p++;
        return next_token;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `strtok` from `<string.h>` handles it like this: "On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Response to edit: Indeed, you should not depend on p being NULL, you should initialize it. But are you only planning to use this function for one string and then be done with it?

Comment: @Kiyura: But `strtok` needs to store a state. That's why the reentrant version requires you to pass an additional variable.

Comment: a static char* is basically a global variable, it simply scopes it to that function, it will never be thread safe.

Comment: @Kiyura well not really. It may run on multiple strings that are given to it through a loop that gathers strings. Also, I don't care about thread safety.

Comment: @Kiyura about strtok, what delimiter would be passed to retrieve each and every character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your edit is wrong.  You are handling the NULL case incorrectly.

I initially answered in terms of emulating `strtok` which seemed to be what you wanted, but you have clarified that you want single characters.

The if-condition should be:

```
if (line != NULL) p = line;
```

And you presumably remove the `else` so that code executes every time...  Unless you don't want a result on the first call (you should at least return a value though).

You call like this:

```
char token = next_token(line);

while( 0 != (token = next_token(NULL)) ) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: This won't work across successive calls. What I want is that assume I have the string "Hello". The first call would return "H", the second would return "e" etc... This resets *p to NULL each and every time so a line has to be passed to it.

Comment: No, you're just not thinking about it correctly.  You asked for something that emulated `strtok`.  That means you store a static.  In the first call, you pass your string.  In successive calls you pass NULL, which means you use your static instead.  The static does not get set to NULL every time, that's just its initial value.  If you just want characters, then take out the searching and string-terminating part.

Comment: How about I edit to allay the negativity regarding my answer... =P

Comment: Running this does not work (taking out the incomplete while loop). But anyway, I removed the last part and fixed a few thingsa and it runs now. Could you just explain how p is not getting set to null each and every call?

Comment: Because that's how you initialise statics.  They are initialised only once, and you can do it like that.  It's just good practise.  Without doing that, it would be uninitialised.  That would be okay, provided your first call doesn't assume it's initialised.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
   char* raw;
   // whatever you need to keep track
} parser_t


void parser_init(parser_t* p, char* s)
{
   // init your parser
}

bool parser_get_token(parser_t* p, char* token)
{
   // return the token in "token"  or return a bool error ( or an enum of various errors)
}

bool parser_peek_token(parser_t* p, char* token)
{
  // same deal, but don't update where you are...
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: no structs as well. Sorry

Comment: why? every solution that trys to store state like strtok is just ugly

Comment: You don't need a state structure..  You just need to pass an extra pointer as `char**` which is used instead of a static.  That makes it thread-safe.  Microsoft's `strtok_s` does this.

Comment: I just can't use structs or global variables for some other reasons

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. One would be to use an interface roughly like `strtok` does, where passing a non-null pointer initializes the static variable, and passing a null pointer retrieves a token. This, however, is fairly ugly, clumsy, error-prone, and problematic in the presence of multithreading.

Another possibility would be to use a file-level static variable with separate functions (both in that file) to initialize the static variable, and to retrieve the next token from the string. This is marginally cleaner, but still have most of the same problems.

A third would be to make it act (for one example) like a file -- the user calls parse_open (for example), passing in the string to parse. You return an opaque handle to them. They then pass that back to (say) get_token each time they want another token.

Comment: "where passing a non-null pointer initializes the static variable, and passing a null pointer retrieves a token". I'm assuming there's a mistake there could you please double check what you meant? Also please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are three ways of a function to pass information back to its caller:

- via a global variable
- via the return value
- via a pointer argument

And, similarly there are ways for the function to maintain state between calls:

- via a global or (function-)static variable
- by supplying it as a function parameter and returning it after every call
- via a pointer argument.

A nice coding convention for a lexer/tokeniser is to use the return value to communicate the number of characters consumed. (and *maybe* use an extra pointer variable to pass the parser state to and fro calls)

This is wakkerbot's parser:

```
STATIC size_t tokenize(char *string, int *sp);
```

Usage:

```
STATIC void make_words(char * src, struct sentence * target)
{
    size_t len, pos, chunk;
    STRING word ;
    int state = 0; /* FIXME: this could be made static to allow for multi-line strings */

    target->size = 0;

    len = strlen(src);
    if (!len) return;

    for(pos=0; pos < len ; ) {

    chunk = tokenize(src+pos, &state);
        if (!chunk) { /* maybe we should reset state here ... */ pos++; }
        if (chunk > STRLEN_MAX) {
            warn( "Make_words", "Truncated too long string(%u) at %s\n", (unsigned) chunk, src+pos);
            chunk = STRLEN_MAX;
            }
        word.length = chunk;
        word.word = src+pos;

        if (word_is_usable(word)) add_word_to_sentence(target, word);

        if (pos+chunk >= len) break;
        pos += chunk;
    }
...
}
```